# SQL Server Job runs successfully, but doesn't execute packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

We have SQL Server 2012. We got `.dtsx` packages that run just fine. We run them manually and they execute properly, but when they are setup to be executed as SQL Server Job, the job executes successfully (no errors), but the SSIS packages are never executed. Nothing happens.

What would be the case? Permissions on packages are setup on FULL for `SQLServerAgent` user and same user is setup to be the owner of that job. Also that same user is setup to be DB admin on server.

Any clues how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you looked at the report for the last execution?

Comment: Have you created your package so that it will return a failure on error?   Have you created the job so that it will quit unsuccessfully on error in the step that calls the package?

Comment: Job history returns following: `Executed as user: NT Service\SQLAgent$CLAIR. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.5058.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  1:15:00 PM  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).  Started:  1:15:00 PM  Finished: 1:15:05 PM  Elapsed:  5.109 seconds.  The package executed successfully.  The step succeeded.` Import job was delivered, but I've tested it by creating it on my own and it is doing the same thing.