# SQL Job completes successfully but does not execute packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-job

I have taken a look at several articles including this unanswered question: [SQL Server Job runs successfully but doesn't execute packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161158/sql-server-job-runs-successfully-but-doesnt-execute-packages)

I have the exact same problem in SQL Server 2012 using the integration services MSDB catalog.  I can execute the SSIS packages manually from that catalog, but the agent job doesn't do anything except state that it completed successfully.  I have also executed my SSIS packages from within Visual Studio and they worked just fine.  Here's the situation and am wondering if it may be permissions:

1. SSIS packages look for Excel files matching criteria in a network location.
2. Once found, the SSIS packages writing the data into the database and archive the file to another folder on that same network location.
3. Emails are sent upon any failure of import of data into the database or migration into the archive folders.

I have the SQL Agent job running the SSIS packages from a package store (MSDB) using the SQL Server Agent Service Account to run under.  Currently we are not doing any sort of project deployment to these servers so I am sticking with package deployment.  Here are some steps I've taken:

1. Run packages manually from Visual Studio 2010 (fully successful).
2. Run packages manually from SQL Server MSDB catalog (fully successful).
3. Run job manually from SQL Server Agent using parent package as a step that will execute child packages as an external reference (success but nothing happens).
4. Run job manually from SQL Server Agent using each package as its own step excluding the parent package (success but nothing happens).

Any ideas?  Permissions to the network location or need a proxy?  Again, I am running Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition 64-bit.  Many thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: After the job runs successfully, look at the package's All Executions report in SSISDB.   Does it show anything about the execution the job should have triggered?

Comment: Hi Tab.  The package isn't in the SSISDB, but instead in the MSDB under the integration services engine.  For instance:

> Running Packages
> Stored Packages
>> File System
>> MSDB
>>> Package1
>>> Package2

Comment: Ah that's unfortunate.  In that case I would go through my package and check, at all levels, the values of the `FailPackageOnFailure` and `FailParentOnFailure` properties.   By default, they are set to False.   You need to set them all to True.   Otherwise, the package will always tell the job it succeeded, even if it didn't, and you may not see any error message.

Comment: Thanks again.  I did enable those options (`FailPackageOnFailure` was greyed out on the package level but not on the parent level so I set it there).  I re-uploaded my packages and it still succeeded.  Very strange.

Comment: Next read through all of your script tasks and make sure that none of them would return a result of success even though they encountered an error.   Be sure to check the ones in your event handlers.

Comment: At the risk of sounding like an idiot, I will have to say I have no literal script tasks and event handlers for this particular project.  Event handlers were going to be added later after I successfully tested these packages.  All other tasks are data flow, file system, send mail, execute sql, Excel datasource, derived column, data conversion, and OLE DB destination tasks (obviously what I said combines both Control Flow and Data Flow tasks).  The parent package simply has three execute SSIS package tasks--one for each child package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  My SSIS package has a foreach loop container and, while the tasks inside the loop container couldn't access the destination, the loop container technically completed successfully.  We had to give permissions to the account the steps were running under for the job to correct that.  These permissions were put on the network location to allow that account access to read and write to that location.  Additionally, my Excel connection was 64-bit so we enabled it to 32-bit runtime and this allowed that portion of the process to complete successfully.  I re-enabled any disabled tasks and it looks good to go now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this scenario many times but when I checked running the package manually,its completing successfully because I was using for each loop container and sequence container as well.In both cases for each loop and sequence were completing without validating other ones.So I checked precedence constraint and change it,Now it working and all the component ran successfully.
Sometimes we miss to choose appropriate precedence constraint, there are many option like on Success ,failure,completion and then for you can choose values from Constraint ,Expression,Expression AND Constraint and Expression OR Constraint.
Initially i was using Expression OR Constraint for success and now changed it to Expression AND Constraint, its working fine for me.
You also need to do this,it will definitely work please try and let me know.